# Basis of neighbourhoods on cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space where $\tau=\{ \emptyset \}\cup \{G\subset E, |E\setminus G|<\infty\}$

How I can write $W_x$ the basis of neighbourhoods  of $x \in E$?

Thank you

Comment: $\tau$ is a basis. There are many bases for $\tau$. What do you mean by "the basis"? Ooh, you mean at $x$ ... just add the condition $x\in G.$

Comment: @Mirko I think it is well written.

Comment: $\{E\in\tau:x\in E\}$ works; so does $$\{G\subseteq E:x\in G\text{ and }|E\setminus G|<\infty\}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write $W_x=\{E \setminus A: A \subseteq E, |A|<\infty, x \notin A\}$. If $U$ is any open neighborhood $x$ then let $E \setminus U \subseteq B$ where $x \notin B$ and $|B|<\infty$ this implies $x \in E \setminus B \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on a set $X$, the set $\mathcal{O}_x = \{O \in \mathcal{T}\mid x \in O\}$ is always **a** base for the topology at $x$, by definition. Of course, smaller bases at $x$ also exist, in general, but this is one you can always use.